# Stop Node Webkit from pausing on unfocus / when minimized

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

Is there a way to keep my Node-Webkit App from pausing when I minimize the window?

Something I can add to the Package.json?

Comment: Did you look at nohup? In your scripts block you may be able to prefix the start with nohup like '"start": "nohup node ./bin/http-server"' (caveat - have not used node-webkit!)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "pausing" when you minimize it?  Are you talking specifically about playing audio, or some other stuff going on?  If the latter, how do you tell that it is paused?

Comment: I guess minimising an app does not pause app but if it happens, could you please give us some details about pausing feature you mentioned in your question.  
But just for a check, You could also try window.hide() on minimise to see If your app still pauses.

Comment: I get this behavior as well. When an app window (nw.gui.Window.get()) has been hidden with .hide(), it appears that setTimeout and setIntervals become paused.or rather, the next function invocation in setInterval doesn't occur until the application becomes visible again.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is too late but anyway in NodeWebkit there is 2 versions of (setInterval/setTimeout) functions:
1- window.setInterval/window.setTimeout (Chrome Version)
2- global.setInterval/global.setTimeout (NodeJs Version)

the NodeJS version will work in background while the Chrome version will pause because it meant to be used for UI and pausing it is better for your application in your case it is obvious that you should use the NodeJs version by using (global.setInterval)

**Note:** if you are facing this issue for some built in modules you can override the chrome version using this little hack:

```
// override chrome timing function with node js versions
this.setTimeout = window.setTimeout = global.setTimeout;
this.clearTimeout = window.clearTimeout = global.clearTimeout;
this.setInterval = window.setInterval = global.setInterval;
this.clearInterval = window.clearInterval = global.clearInterval;
```

Cheers ;)